# From Buffer("string", "hex) to string JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, hex, buffer

I'm writing a function to reduce the key by 2 times. The function accepts a key in the following form:

```
Buffer.from('0xe581d529cc69816e768432a8aa09178470c9b1e703951f4a85e0dab7d8008e2a9e9e179', 'hex')
```

so that I can reduce the key I need to convert it to a string. The `toString()` or `toString('hex')` method do not work.

I also tried using sha256 encryption for the key, but when I called the function with different keys I still got the same value after hashing.

Checking the value of a key or its length using `console.log()` showed that the length was 0, but when printing the key it did not output anything.

Comment: Try removing the `0x` prefix.

Comment: Yes, I have already tried this option and it works. But the input function will receive a key with the prefix "0x"

Comment: So, you can just detect that and trim it off.

Comment: But how can I do this? If I create a variable, I can’t do anything with it, because Node JS “says” that there is nothing in the variable, it’s empty.

const key = Buffer.from('0xe581d529cc69816e768432a8aa09178470c9b1e703951f4a85e0dab7d8008e2a9e9e179', 'hex')

Comment: Does something [like this](http://tpcg.io/_F8SZM2) not work for you?

Comment: Yes, what you suggest works. I can convert a key without the "0x" prefix to toString("hex") and do whatever I want.
But the key will be sent to the input of the function with a prefix. While the key is in the buffer, with the refix “0x” and the encoding “hex”, I can’t do anything.

Comment: If the key is sent as a string, you can take a substring. If the key is already in a text buffer, you can `slice` the buffer or just use the `start` parameter of `toString` _e.g._ `toString('hex', 2)`. Read the [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/ref_buffer.asp) and if you're still confused then show a _representative_ example of what your looks like, not some contrived example.